# Why are my tests in the gitlab-pipeline failing?

Tags: python, gitlab, pytest, gitlab-ci, cicd

Im currently busy creating a pipeline for my testscripts in Gitlab. I have written the scripts in pytest in python.
I have 13 scripts and these all pass when i run it in PyCharm.

I have added a .gitlab-ci.yml file to my project. I look like this:

```py
stages:
  - test
  - build
variables:
  http_proxy: xxx
  https_proxy: xxx
  no_proxy: "*.xxx.nl,firefox"
  BROWSER: firefox

pytest_bdd:
  stage: test
  image:
    name: xxx/library/python:3.11.3-slim
    entrypoint:
    - ''
  services:
    - name: xxx/docker-hub/selenium/standalone-firefox
      alias: firefox
  before_script:
  - python -V
  - python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
  script:
  - pytest --log-cli-level=INFO -vvv -n 3
```

When i commit my changes to Gitlab the tests will be triggered in the pipeline. But half of my test fails. They all have the same error message:
FAILED steps/test_gui_tests.py::test_sectie_teeltvoorschriften - selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Could not start a new session. New session request timed out.

Does anyone has an idea why the tests are failing? It seems that there is not enough memory, but how do I find out and how can I increase the memory?
I also have login built into my script. But I don't see this in the pipeline. Is there any special login in the pipeline?